# Stuck on Boot Screen - LightningFastRom - LineageOS - 17.1

Tags: lineageos, supersu

I recently installed [LightningFastRom 17.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lightningfastrom-17-1-q-10-for-gtelwifiue-gtesqltespr.4231493/), a ROM based off LineageOS 17.1, for my Galaxy Tab E 9.6 (SM-T560NU-gtelwifiue). For GApps, I used OpenGApps (arm, 10.0, micro). I modified the .zip file using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxW72-Nzb3A&ab_channel=EncryptedGuy). When I first booted it, it worked perfectly, then I flashed [SuperSU](https://supersuroot.org/). I waited an entire day and it still didn't boot. Does anyone know how to get back to recovery while on the boot screen, I decided to flash a new ROM.
[image: StuckOnBootScreen]

Comment: Why have you use SuperSU instead of Magisk?

Comment: I used SuperSU before I started using Magisk. I decided to try SuperSU again. I have a Galaxy Grand Prime (SM-G530, gprimelte) and I flashed Magisk on that. That's also stuck on boot. It uses LineageOS 16.0.